# Run a powershell script from python where the path contains spaces

Tags: python, powershell

I've found that python can run other programs using the subprocess module.  I want to use python to run a powershell script that is in a directory location that contains spaces.  How do I handle the spaces in the python script below?

```
import subprocess
powershellExeLocation = r"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
powershellScriptLocation = r"C:\Users\username\Documents\testPowershell.ps1"
print('running script with no spaces')
#this works
subprocess.run([powershellExeLocation, powershellScriptLocation])
#this doesn't work
print('running script with spaces')
powershellScriptLocationWithSpaces = r"C:\Users\username\path with spaces\testPowershell.ps1"
subprocess.run([powershellExeLocation, powershellScriptLocationWithSpaces])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
subprocess.run([powershellExeLocation, "-File", powershellScriptLocationWithSpaces])
```

Answer (score 0):

The script location needs a set of literal quotes around it, so powershell.exe knows to treat it as one single filename.

```
subprocess.run([powershellExeLocation, '"' + powershellScriptLocationWithSpaces + '"'])
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I added quotes as shown to paths with and without spaces and it broke the ability to run the script in both cases.

Comment: There is no error produced, but it behaves as if the path to the powershell script was not found - the powershell window opens and closes immediately, rather than running the script.